# vim-t line split not working

Tags: line-breaking, context, vim, bash

I'm using context on my mac machine. I'm trying to wrap lines automatically using lines=split when defining vim typing, but it's not working.

This is how I define vim typing at the very top of my .tex file:

```
\usemodule [vim]
\definevimtyping [BASH] [syntax=bash][lines=split]
```

and here you can see how I'm using it:

```
\startBASH
        curl -X GET 'http://ags.cuzk.cz/arcgis/rest/services/RUIAN/Prohlizeci_sluzba_nad_daty_RUIAN/MapServer/17/query?objectIds=415&outFields=+objectId,nazev&returnGeometry=true&f=geojson'
\stopBASH
```

Below you can see that lines are not wrapped. I tried to replace this URL (which is now clickable) with regular string, but I had same result.

[image]

**Solution:**
I was defining vimtyping wrong.

lines=split should be in [] together with syntax and you have to add option=hypenated as well:

`\definevimtyping [BASH] [syntax=bash, lines=split, option=hypenated]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set multiple options for a vim instance you have to put all of them in the same argument and not use a separate argument for each option.

A line break in the URL can be achieved with the `hyphenated` keyword for the `option` key. To avoid overfull lines with text which extends into the right margin set options like `verytolerant` for the `align` key.

```
\usemodule [vim]

\definevimtyping
  [BASH]
  [syntax=bash,
   lines=split,
   align=verytolerant,
   option=hyphenated]

\starttext

\startBASH
curl -X GET 'http://ags.cuzk.cz/arcgis/rest/services/RUIAN/Prohlizeci_sluzba_nad_daty_RUIAN/MapServer/17/query?objectIds=415&outFields=+objectId,nazev&returnGeometry=true&f=geojson'
\stopBASH

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! verytolerant align was very helpful